# How to Format MP3 Length Time from String Like 00:00:00 in PHP

Tags: php

I store the length of an MP3 in MYSQL as a string formatted like `00:00:00` example: `01:23:15`.

I'm trying to build a function to format that in a more user friendly way that removes hours`,`minutes`as the case may be and do not show leading zeros or`:`.

`02:43:12` would become `2:45:12` (in this case the leading zero on the hours is removed)

`02:03:12` would become `2:03:12` (in this case the leading zero on the minutes is needed visually because there are hours present)

`00:18:28` would become `18:28` (in this case the leading zeros for hours and the `:` is removed)

`00:08:28` would become `8:28` (in this case the leading zero on the minutes is not needed because there are no hours present)

`00:00:14` would become `00:14` (in this case if minutes are zero then it should still show the two leading zeros so it's clear you're seeing seconds only)

`00:00:04` would become `00:04` (in this case both the leading zeros for minutes and seconds show to make it more readable)

Comment: So what have you tried?, can be achieved by just splitting up the parts and putting conditions on them..

Comment: @LawrenceCherone i sorta tried that but had a ton of if statements and it felt super clunky. Thought there might be a more elegant way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to do lots of conditions you could also do it like this with simple `str_replace()` and a final check to remove leading 0 from `02:43:12`

```
<?php
$tests = [
    '12:43:23',    
    '02:43:12',    
    '02:03:12',    
    '00:18:28',    
    '00:08:28',    
    '00:00:14',    
    '00:00:04',   
    '00:00:00',
];

function mp3time($str) {
    $str = str_replace(['00:0', '00:', '0:'], ['', '', '00:'], $str);

    if (strlen($str) === 8 && $str[0] == 0) {
        $str = substr($str, 1);
    }

    return $str;
}

foreach ($tests as $timestamp) {
    echo mp3time($timestamp).PHP_EOL;
}
```

**Result:**

```
12:43:23
2:43:12
2:03:12
18:28
8:28
00:14
00:04
00:00
```

https://3v4l.org/H4A06

Comment: Ahh.. yes, that works. Thank you so much. Errors when hours are 2 digits `12:43:23` but I fixed it.

Comment: Cool, nice catch, I've fixed it, thanks for the accept

Answer (score 0):

@Larence Cherones solution worked for me but I found 2 additional use cases that didn't work right. If the minutes were `:00` or the seconds were `:00` formatting messed up. Couldn't figure out a good way to modify his code to accommodate those cases so I came up with this hybrid of his solution.

```
function format_track_time($time) {

   $a = substr($time, 0, 3); // hours
   $b = substr($time, 3, 3); // minutes
   $c = substr($time, 6, 2); // seconds
   $a = str_replace(['00:'], [''], $a);

   $time = $a . $b . $c;

   // REMOVE LEADING ZERO FOR HOURS
   if (strlen($time) == 8 && $time[0] == '0') {
       $time = substr($time, 1);
   } 
   // REMOVE LEADING ZERO FOR MINUTES IF NO HOURS
   if (strlen($time) == 5 && $time[0] == '0') {
       $time = substr($time, 1);
   }

   return $time;    
}
```